# FACEBOOK API : How do I get the long-lived access token from PHP API

Tags: php, facebook, api, access-token

My question: how to get long-lived access token from PHP API. I have read through all the prior posts about this matter and still don't have the answer.
Basically, I get a short-lived access token from the API explorer. Subsquently, I wrote a simple PHP prohgram invoking the facebook graph API to request a long-lived access token. Yet, it isn't working. I am missing something here. Here is the snippet of the PHP code that I wrote:

```
  $response = $fb->request("GET", "GET /oauth/access_token?  
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&           
    client_id={my app id}&
    client_secret={my app secret}&
    fb_exchange_token={'the short-lived token obtained from the api 
   explorer'}")
    ..//error checking...
      //

    // then I call this:
    $token = $response->getaccessToken();
   // end of program
```

It turns out the getaccessToken() return the same short-lived token that I passed to the API. So, I am running of idea of how to make it work.

According to the API doc, the call with the input parameter of "fb_exhcnage_token" is supposed to return a "long-lived access token".
Yet, I am not getting it.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk/blob/2f9639c15ae043911f40ffe44080b32bac2c5280/docs/getting_started.md#extending-the-access-token

Comment: Thanks. I did what the soc suggested. Yet, no difference

Comment: What makes it even more odd is that the call never return any error code if I passed in a invalidated expired short-lived access code. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: `$fb->request("GET", "GET /oauth/` is wrong, remove the second GET.

Comment: Also, you did remove the `{}`, right? Those only mean "insert value here" ...

Comment: Thanks for the reply; Yes, I did correct the ("GET", "GET ...) error. The following is a exact  copy of the code: $fb->request("get", "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/oauth/access_token?

Comment: And I did remove the {}.  I am really running of the idea of how to debug this thing.

Comment: I can email you a copy of the code, if I may.

Comment: I call the ghetaccessToken () to get the long-lived access token.     $long_lived_token = $response->getaccessToken();

Comment: try {  $response = $fb->request("get", 
                             "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/oauth/access_token?  
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&           
    client_id=1119412345678946583&
    client_secret=a9dcd121c50492e1d1c8bf4707bff2df&
    fb_exchange_token=EAABlz33IyoYBBASZCkGZChZAsZB5uDbkreFijlh1Mc9dvEKTwSREqovyN88f4xfWVTCyp43kZAMDYwshKMk5Wvqb04D3XRQZApBnYSsB9Jr9cBHfIWML9pGLKCLSK9w2usSfi5A9mWzRQf6SPuOw3zIJAl5wPAUBl8V9ZAM04KTi6eiMQCyT3BCZCthrRoeiBThUZD"); 
} catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  ..error routin...}

Comment: _“I can email you a copy of the code, if I may”_ - please edit the question instead. And don’t ever publicly expose the app secret or tokens.

Comment: Those are not the real secret or token key that I obtained from the FB. I replaced part of the real token with some random data before I posted it. thx for the reminder, though.

Comment: @CBore:  Edit what question? Let me know if you need any more information about the matter? I really run out of idea  of how to make it work. thxm

Comment: I meant put your actual current code into this question please (edit it), instead of dumping it in a comment, where it is hardly readable.

Answer (score 0):

This is valid in 2019, after long-term tokens became 60-day expiries. Here are Facebook's instructions to swap a short-term token (provided in front-end) for a long-term token (server only):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing/

```
Generate a Long-lived User or Page Access Token
You will need the following:

A valid User or Page Access Token
Your App ID
Your App Secret
Query the GET oath/access_token endpoint.

curl -i -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/{graph-api-version}/oauth/access_token?  
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token           
    client_id={app-id}&
    client_secret={app-secret}&
    fb_exchange_token={your-access-token}" 

Sample Response
{
  "access_token":"{long-lived-access-token}",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "expires_in": 5183944            //The number of seconds until the token expires
}
```

You can make this curl request in PHP using `curl_init()`:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

---

Or if you would rather use the Facebook PHP SDK, you can do this:

1.) Create a FB request object with your credentials.
2.) Request long-term token using the FB object and the access token

```
public function createFacebookRequestObject($facebookUser)
    {
        try {
            return new Facebook([
                'app_id' => config('env.FACEBOOK_GRAPH_API_ID'),
                'app_secret' => config('env.FACEBOOK_GRAPH_API_SECRET'),
                'default_graph_version' => 'v4.0',
                'default_access_token' => $facebookUser->access_token
            ]);
        } catch (\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
            return 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

public function fetchLongTermAccessToken($fb, $facebookUser)
        {
            return $fb->get(
                "/oauth/access_token?grant_type=
                fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=" 
              . $facebookUser['access_token']  
                . '&client_id=' 
                . config('env.FACEBOOK_APP_ID'), );
        }
```